# Python function string index out of range

Tags: python, error-handling

```
def search_Lm_in_df_two(collection,dataset): 
        for element in collection:
            for row in dataset[1:]:
                if element == row[5]: <-- #This is where the error is
                    lmstring = row[6]
                    newString = {shorten_string(lmstring)}
        return newString
```

Getting this index error. Just comparing a collection with ID's with elements in a csv file.

Tried solutions from similar threads, but it won't work.

> IndexError: string index out of range

Comment: You should provide an example input data and the entire error trace including the line where it's failing.

Comment: Can you give us what the collection and dataset variable is and give us your expected output.

Answer (score 0):

Referring to your inline comment which points to

```
if element == row[5]
```

as the line throwing an error, I'd wager that at least one `element` in the rows of your dataset contain strings shorter than 6 characters (which would cause an index error).

You could create a band-aid for these elements by replacing your `if` statement with a `try-except`:

```
def search_Lm_in_df_two(collection,dataset): 
    for element in collection:
        for row in dataset[1:]:

            try element == row[5]: # Try this, unless it throws an error.
                lmstring = row[6]
                newString = {shorten_string(lmstring)}

            except: # If something goes wrong, use a default and continue.
                lmstring = a_default_value
                newString = another_default_value

    return newString
```

For due diligence, though, I'd suggest an investigation into the dataset to identify how many elements have problematic string lengths. There might be several. Perhaps those elements are worth dealing with separately.

Side-note: It looks like the `newString` variable is being set over and over in this loop, but returned after all of the nested for loops are complete. Which means your search function only returns the latest value of newString. Is this intentional?

Comment: the thing is row[5] is not about the input length, it's pointing on the sixth cell in a dataframe. So my dataframe has at least 1000 rows and I would like to compare the id's from the frame with the ones in the collection.

Comment: But thanks for the advice with the "newString" you're right with that!! :)